# Can't enable remote desktop in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I can't enable remote desktop in Windows 10 Pro (build 1803).

I toggle the button.

[image: pic1].

click confirm.

[image: pic2].

but the service is not toggled on.

[image: pic3].

However, when I check the classic way of enabling RDP, it shows the service being ticked on. But unable to remote in. I did restart the RDP service too.

[image: pic4].

I was able to activate the RDP service by disabling the firewall rules under Public network settings.

[image: pic5]
[image: pic6]

Unsure what rules is causing this issue yet.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? If from outside the network, make sure you have port forwarding set up.

Comment: I was able to activate the RDP service by disabling the firewall rules under Public network settings. Unsure what rules is causing this issue yet. see the updated images for clarity. the issue is that the service is started on the system due to some rules - something is preventing it.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the computer from? On the same network or outside of it?

Comment: within the same network. I have figured out the issue now. The network profile was set to Public instead of Private. Under Private, with FW enabled, you can enable the RDP service without any issue.

Comment: Add it as the answer if it resolves the issue.

Comment: added the solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have figured out the issue now. The network profile was set to Public instead of Private. Under Private, with FW enabled, you can enable the RDP service without any issue. But when the profile is set for Public and with FW enabled, the RDP service isn't allowed to start by default it seems. Unless manual configurations are done.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! Do you want to set it as Answer?

Comment: where should I change a network profile ? As always, windows searchbar is useless. Where is this settings located ?

Comment: Right in the bull's-eye! Excellent answer, helped us a lot!

Comment: while this works, it still doesn't make the checkbox enabled.