# Cannot enable remote desktop on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

i have a very similar question to what is here

[cant enable remote desktop in windows 10 pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1377451/cant-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-10-pro)

except none of the solution here has helped.

- windows has been updated
- firewall for both private and public networks are off
- IPV6 is turned off
- remote desktop service is running
- the settings have been changed through the old UI
- battery settings have been adjusted

still cant RDP any other ideas?

Comment: How are you testing, internally or externally?

Comment: What error do you get when you try RD?

Comment: My entire hardware is now being replaced :) for good or bad. hopefully this issue will end. @music2myear

Comment: So this is a business environment?

Comment: Yes. Not personal